How to fix QQmlApplicationEngine Error in KDE Connect on Ferdora(xfce)?
I've tried to install KDE Connect on my PC. I am running the XFCE Spin of Fedora.
If I click on the desktop icon, nothing is happening. I have already tried running it in the terminal but if I run kdeconnect-app the response is:
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/qt/qml/org/kde/kdeconnect/app/Main.qml: module "org.kde.desktop" is not installed

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
Thanks in advanced.
